# JQuery validation: At least one of several number inputs must be above 0

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with three Javascript-calculated inputs which default to 0.

In order for the form to get validated, at least one of the fields must have a value above 0.

How can I do this successfully?
I already know about the 'require_from_group' validation method to make sure one of several fields are filled, but is there something similar to check the value of these fields?

**JS:**

```
    $('#registerForm').validate({
     rules: {
      gramsTOT: {
       require_from_group: [1, '.notZero']
      },
      unitsTOT: {
       require_from_group: [1, '.notZero']
      },
      eurcalcTOT: {
       require_from_group: [1, '.notZero']
      }
     }, // end rules
    }); // end validate
```

**HTML:**

```
    <input type='number' lang='nb' class='specialInput first notZero' id='gramsTOT' name='gramsTOT' value="0" readonly /><br />
    <input type='number' lang='nb' class='specialInput first notZero' id='unitsTOT' name='unitsTOT' value="0" readonly /><br />
    <input type='number' lang='nb' class='specialInput notZero' id='eurcalcTOT' name='eurcalcTOT' value="0" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.validator.addMethod` to build custom validation rule, in your case it would be

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("greater_than_number", function(value, element, options) {
  var val = $(options[1], element.form).filter(function() {

    return $(this).val();

  }).val(); 
  console.log(val);
  var valid = parseFloat(val) > parseFloat(options[0]) ;
  console.log(valid);
  return valid;
}, jQuery.validator.format('one of these must bigger than {0}'));



$('#myform').validate({
  rules: {
    gramsTOT: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.notZero'],
      greater_than_number: [0, '.notZero']
    },
    unitsTOT: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.notZero'],
      greater_than_number: [0, '.notZero']
    },
    eurcalcTOT: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.notZero'],
      greater_than_number: [0, '.notZero']
    }
  }, // end rules
}); // end validate
```

See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/e3k7hfd5/)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch!
Now over to the hard part, analysing and understanding your code... :-)